# sed and replace string by a $variable

Tags: bash, sed

I have a little problem.

I try to replace a string(well a line) by a $variable in a file.

So I use the command :

```
sed -i -e "s/conf .*/conf = $PATH_CONF/g" generals.conf
```

If PATH_CONF does not contains specials characters like "/", it's working.

But PATH_CONF contains a path(/home/etc.) so it has several "/", then I got an error :

```
 bad flag in substitute command: 'h'
```

So how must I do to have specials characters in my $variable ?

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
sed -i -e "s@conf .*@conf = $PATH_CONF@g" generals.conf
```

You need the identical chars as separators (here @), not three /s necessarily.

Comment: wow nice, didn't knew of this.

Comment: thanks a lot, didn't know either